# Why does matrix-vector multiplication in Python get faster after the first call?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

n = 10
trials = 10

def test(scale=0.1):
    A = np.random.normal(scale=scale, size=(n, n))
    v = np.random.normal(scale=scale, size=(n))
    start = timer()
    A @ v
    end = timer()
    print('Time: ', end-start)

for _ in range(trials):
    test()
```

The output is:

```
Time:  0.0036287959665060043
Time:  7.0838723331689835e-06
Time:  3.401888534426689e-06
Time:  3.093155100941658e-06
Time:  3.0230730772018433e-06
Time:  3.037974238395691e-06
```

Why are the first two trials so much slower? The context is that I am working on a project where I need to report the speedup of one method (for matrix-vector multiplication in a specialized case) over general matrix-vector multiplication. Should I ignore the first few trials, and if so, why?

Comment: Possibly intermediate results are cached, try timing with the `timeit` module for more accurate timings

Comment: It's probably not about the multiplication that takes time, but the init of the random or something similar. Try running the `np.random.normal(...)` outside of the method first to see if that has any effect

Comment: I can't replicate your timings BTW

Comment: @Chris_Rands I've updated the code snippet and timings with the `timeit` module.

Comment: I _can_ replicate the timings. After playing around and running the code many times, the first call is now only 4 times as slow as the first, with the same exact code. Cached libraries at the OS level must somehow be part of the answer.

Comment: @Wolph also tried that (calling `np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(n,n))` `trials` times first, outside of the method), similar results.

Comment: that's not the right way to use it, try something like `timeit.timeit('test()', setup="from __main__ import test", number=10000)` and look at the final time (this is timing the whole funciton of course)

Comment: You should be using one of the timeit functions that performs your computation in a loop, so that variations due to system load are averaged out. From your figures, I recommend at least 1000 loops. Also, timeit will (by default) disable garbage collection while it performs its timings because garbage collection can otherwise mess up the results.

Comment: Ninja'd by Chris. That timeit function can also be used to time expressions, not just functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Chris_Rands and @PM 2Ring. Sorry if this is obvious, but what is the best way to exclude the time for the random generation of `A` and `v` when using `timeit.timeit`?

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005114/timeit-function-with-random-list).